# Eclipse: Disposing error while closing a file/project

Tags: eclipse

Upon closing a file/project I see a pop up wuth the message:

```
Disposing has encountered a problem. An internal error has occurred. java.lang.NullPointerException
```

My environment is:

- Windows 7
- Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
- Version: Juno
- Service Release 2
- Build id: 20130225-0426

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: I have the same problem. Same platform and build id and same circumstances.

Comment: Does anyone has any solution ? I dont see it with Linux ubuntu 3.2.0-29-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 27 17:03:23 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux and eclipse Version: 3.7.2
Build id: I20110613-1736

Comment: Is there more information in the log file in the .metadata folder?

Answer (score 1):

IF it's caused by m2e, upgrade m2e 0.x to released 1.4. The problem will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

this is a bug reported in eclipse

go thorough this link for detailed information

[bug in eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=371534)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be deleted the files from workspace and try to close or open the file which was previously opened befor you delete that file in workspace

Answer (score 0):

Try download the newer version of Eclipse (Keppler), the problem is fixed that error on that version

Answer (score 0):

You can install another version, or you can re-install.